# Django user access control

Tags: django

For example, I have one model `Post`.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey("User")
```

I want users can only access posts created by themselves but have too many views which list some posts to rewrite queryset in each view.

So is there any graceful way to control user access? Save and get current user in thread and implement a new `Manager` class to `Post` is a way, but I don't know why this is not recommended.

Comment: Have your tried **`Post.objects.filter(task=logged_in_user)`** in somewhere in your code?

Comment: Override the `get_queryset` method on your views, and implement something like @ArakkalAbu suggests in it.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, of course, but in this way, I need to change every view class or method

Comment: Yes, you should change every view you would like to change. Because, the ***model managers*** can not ***auto fetch*** the ***logged-in user*** and filter them

Comment: @ChidG, this is a better way, but my views are inherit from different `django.views.generic` view template and some even just functions.

Comment: Now you can decide *"how to change"*. You could write a simple mixin and inherit in the required views, also you could overwrite the `get_queryset()` method or *similar methods* in each views

Comment: If you're using functional views, you could write a decorator to wrap them. If you're using class based views, why wouldn't you be inheriting them from the inbuilt generic ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using generic [**`ListView`**(Django-doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). You can override the [**`get_queryset(...)`**(Django-doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method of view as below,

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(task=self.request.user)
```

---

### Generic Solution

First you need to create a mixin class,

```
class GenericLoggedInMixin:
    user_field_name = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if self.user_field_name:
            return queryset.filter(**{self.user_field_name: self.request.user})
        return queryset
```

and inherit the same in your view as,

```
class PostListView(GenericLoggedInMixin, ListView):
    user_field_name = 'task'
```

Comment: Thanks, the generic solution is exactly what I want.